# Question about Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

A friend of mine told me that for fourier series 
If the function is odd or even and have its reflection on x-achse after half the period (u(t+T/2)=-u(t)) 
then one of the coefficient is zero (no problem with this) and the other one is the definition of Fourier coefficient normally but multiplied by 8 and integrated till quarter of the period .

Is this true ?

I asked the question here because I am in holiday now and i don't have anyone other than the Internet to ask

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you integrate on a quarter of the period, and the integrand is identical on the four quarters, then you get four times the value, don't you ?

Comment: No because the function is multiplied by cosine , which is  not repeated four times